# set AllowOverride to All in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, httpd.conf

I have an app that I am trying to deploy with Beanstalk AWS Linux 2023. It’s a PHP app, however, I need Apache to use the .htaccess file in order to complete a rewrite and prevent a 404 error on all links. I have tried .ebextensions and created a config file to enable mod rewrite file it fails. So is there a way to continue the AllowOverride from none to All with a .platform or a setting to allow a custom httpd.conf?